# Unicode character crashing an app after setText

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

Here's a simple code that seems to crash my app in the latest Xcode, it worked fine in earlier versions, does anyone know why it suddenly started happening now or if Apple has changed UILabels recently.

Here's a sample text that crashes the app, a few unicode characters work but 'ᴀ' crashes it.

```
UILabel *my_label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[my_label setText:@"ᴀ"]; // unicode character
[self.view addSubview:my_label];
```

I'm also using the same systemFont as before.

Comment: I did not try this but.. try NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"0xF09F948A"]; find unicode for your character and than set myString as text to your label

Comment: Then the label just shows the text '0xF09F948A' instead of the unicode.

Comment: Give me sometime let me try this ..

Comment: @ValayPatel thank you, please let me know if you find anything, so weird!?!

Comment: I tried [label setText:@"\u1d00"]; but that still crashes the app.

Comment: Are u sure it's crashing at this point.. It may hv some other issue...

Comment: Did you try with normal "ABC" text

Comment: I don't believe this code ever "worked fine". Please provide details of the crash. Also please explain what on earth is the point of making a label of zero size.

Comment: @ValayPatel I'm fetching twitter users and many have unicodes in their usernames.

Comment: @matt sorry, this is just a sample code it also crashes with normal sizes.

Comment: @zaph even after doing that it still crashes, tried it on my macbook running an older version of Xcode and seems to be working fine, updating Xcode on there and seeing if it starts crashing, will keep you guys updated!

Comment: What I'm saying is that no one would write the code you've shown, and no one can reproduce the crash, so this is not a very useful report.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me..

I did simply IBOutLet instead

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel * my_label;
}

@end


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [my_label setText:@"\u1d00"]; // unicode character
    [self.view addSubview:my_label];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And it worked perfectly fine no crash